# PHP Run-Time Array Creation

Tags: php

Sometime we need to create a multidimensional array on demand when we do not know the dimension in advance. Suppose I have the following code where I like to make a multidimensional array on the presence of '_' in the given string. Here this given string is the $table from which I like to construct a multidimensional array.

```
$table='Customer_Contacts';
$fi='City';
$fv='New York';    
$explodedTableName=explode('_', $table);
$tobeEvaluatedArray="\$association";
foreach($explodedTableName as $etn){
   $tobeEvaluatedArray.="['$etn']";
}
$tobeEvaluatedArray.="['$fi']=$fv";
eval($tobeEvaluatedArray);
```

Now I want to get an array ,namely,

```
$association['Customer']['Contacts']['City']='New York';
```

Comment: Have you read about [how to create arrays with PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)?

Comment: The document is not helping me.

Comment: The answer is almost a very good one.

Comment: I do not understand why this question has been put on hold. Ridiculous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want this dynamic.  This should work and give you an idea to customize:

```
$table = 'Customer_Contacts';

$keys = explode('_', $table);
$keys[] = 'City';
$value = 'New York';

$temp = &$result;

foreach($keys as $key) {
    $temp =& $temp[$key];
}
$temp = $value;

print_r($result);
```